# Can't rename a Maya locked node

Tags: python, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def replace(char):
    locators = cmds.ls(tr=True, s=True,type=('joint')) or []

    try:
        for lp in locators:
            if char in lp:
                newFilename = lp.replace(char, "a")
                cmds.rename(lp, newFilename)
    except:
        print "yes"

charReplace="Ghoul"
charReplace2="SHJnt"
charReplace3="head"
charReplace4="spine"
charReplace5="arm"
charReplace6="leg"

replace(charReplace)
replace(charReplace2)
replace(charReplace3)
replace(charReplace4)
replace(charReplace5)
replace(charReplace6)
```

I'm trying to rename all the nodes in a Maya scene.

This current code only renames these nodes: Ghoul and SHJnt.

I can't rename the head node.

I get the following error when I try to rename it:
`// Error: line 1: Cannot rename a locked node. //`

How can I improve my code to be able to rename locked nodes?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow. Please avoid using screenshots containing code, it's way faster for you to copy/paste it in your question and way easier for us to execute it. No one will recopy your code if you provide a screenshot.
Try to clearly explain what your problem is and you want to resolve it.
Also, if you have any, try to provide an error stack. 
You can check on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I'll be happy to help you once your question will have been edited and improved.
Hang in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

########################################
# This function renames Maya nodes whose name contains oldString value
# newString is an optionnal argument 
########################################
def renameNode(oldString, newString="a"):
    # I don't really understand why you are passing these flags in the ls() function
    # node_list = cmds.ls(tr=True, s=True,type=('joint'))
    # I would recommand to only list nodes that might interest you using *
    # * acts as a wildcard
    node_list = cmds.ls( "*" + oldString + "*", tr=True )

    # Iterate through each node in the list
    for node in node_list:
        # Now unlock the node entirely 
        # You can also check the doc for the flag lockName
        cmds.lockNode(node, lock=False)
        # Rename the node
        cmds.rename( node, node.replace(oldString, newString) )


renameNode("Ghoul")
renameNode("SHJnt")
renameNode("head")
renameNode("spine")
renameNode("arm", "NewName")  
renameNode("leg", "OtherName")
```

- `newString` is an optionnal parameter, it's default value is a
- This code will unlock the nodes but will not lock them after renaming
- I'm not renaming shapes as renaming a transform automatically renames the shape.

Comment: Thank you so much!